# How can I block external connections with RSpec & Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, capybara

With my Rails project, I would like to write tests non-ideal conditions such as lack of internet connection or timeouts.  For example, I am using a gem to contact an API and would like to make sure that I handle the error correctly if there is a connection issue between my app and the external API.

I can do this already by making a fixture with VCR and removing the response from the "cassette".  However, this has drawbacks:

- It has to be done manually.
- The cassettes can not be gitignored if I am working with a team(which I am).

How can I simply create a block in my RSpec tests that will prevent external connections, simulating the lack of an internet connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never tried to do this, but perhaps you could use [webmock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock) to stub out all requests.

```
before do 
  stub_request(:any, /.*/).to_return(body: "errors", status: 422)
end
```

[More info](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-to-stub-external-services-in-tests) on stubbing external services.

Comment: Thank you!  This works perfectly.  The only other thing I had to do was add ```require 'webmock/rspec'``` to spec_helper.rb.

Comment: This article is great but what if I only want to disable internet connection without having to add a gem as big as webmock?

Answer (score 12):

Per this thought-bot article

https://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-to-stub-external-services-in-tests#disable-all-remote-connections

```
# spec/spec_helper.rb
require 'webmock/rspec'
WebMock.disable_net_connect!(allow_localhost: true)
```

Comment: Wow, I like that a lot! I will have to try it the next chance I get. Seems like it would be a preferred method.

Comment: You can then specify the stub response for the requests that do get issued:

      stub_request(:get, "url.goes.here").
          to_return(status: 200, body: "some response", headers: {})

Comment: This is a great article but it only works for me with   
`Net::HTTP.get(uri)`   
But not with Rspec's   
`get(uri)`