# Is there a way to cut internet access to ruby processes?

Tags: ruby, testing, continuous-integration, minitest, stub

I have ruby processes such as running tests which are relying on internet access.
I'd like to know which of them are relying on it.

I'm currently using minitest as a testing framework but instead of actually using minitest/mock, WebMock, Mocha or something else to stub, I'd like to know if there's a plain Ruby way to cut internet access of processes.

Is that possible?

Comment: Run it in a VM with no networking enabled. That'll expose problems really quick.

Comment: Why not just running the tests without internet connection (switch off wifi or unplug the network cable) and see what tests are failing?

Comment: Because I want my whole CI to be hermetic and other developers to have red tests if they introduce non hermetic tests.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I block external connections with RSpec & Capybara?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26130939/how-can-i-block-external-connections-with-rspec-capybara)

Comment: It would only be part of the solution to me as I'm not only using WebMock.